# Два шейдера, в одном текстура в пространстве экрана, в другом - на объекте

Tags: unity3d, шейдеры

Есть два шейдера воды. 
У обоих есть поле `_ReflectionTex ("Internal Reflection", 2D) = "" {}`

Когда вешаешь эти шейдера на объект и кладешь в это поле текстуру - картина принципиально разная -

Первый шейдер, Oney, заливает этой картинкой объект, растягивая её по нему.

Второй шейдер, FX/Water, заливает картинкой пространство экрана - и именно этот функционал нужен нам и для первого шейдера!

Код обращения с картинкой у обоих шейдеров примерно одинаковый - и там и там они берут `TEXTCOORD0`, делают с его помощью операцию 
`half4 refl = tex2Dproj( _ReflectionTex, UNITY_PROJ_COORD(uv1) );`
 и затем присваивают значение этой текстуры там, где есть прозрачность исходной текстуры. Отражение в воде, в общем. Но повторюсь, эффект абсолютно разный.

Хотелось бы сделать так, чтобы шейдер Oney при сохранении всего своего функционала, умел бы накладывать текстуру в пространство экрана(а не одного объекта), как это успешно делает шейдер FX/Water

Код ниже, и, чтобы сэкономить немного места - он чуть урезан. Так что если не хватает пары переменных - это из за этого, исходный код просто примерно в полтора раза больше.

```
Shader "Oney" {  //Всем хорош, но не может в наложение текстур на экран. 
    Properties {
        _Color ("Color", Color) = (0.7016652,0.8427501,0.9264706,1)
        _Color_Waves ("Color_Waves", Color) = (0.1096453,0.3823529,0.2920773,1)
        _Normal_1 ("Normal_1", 2D) = "bump" {}
        _Normal_2 ("Normal_2", 2D) = "bump" {}
        _Waves ("Waves", 2D) = "white" {}
        _CubMap ("CubMap", Cube) = "_Skybox" {}
        _Intensity_Waves ("Intensity_Waves", Range(0, 50)) = 10
        _Speed ("Speed", Range(0, 1)) = 0.1
        _Intensity_Color ("Intensity_Color", Range(0, 10)) = 5
        _Spec ("Spec", Range(0, 2)) = 1
        _Gloss ("Gloss", Range(0, 2)) = 1
        _Reflection ("Reflection", Range(0, 2)) = 0
         _ReflectionTex ("Internal Reflection", 2D) = "" {}
    }
    SubShader {
        Tags {
            "RenderType"="Opaque"
        }
        Pass {
            Name "FORWARD"
            Tags {
                "LightMode"="ForwardBase"
            }


            CGPROGRAM

            uniform sampler2D _Normal_2; uniform float4 _Normal_2_ST;
            uniform float _Intensity_Color;
            uniform float4 _Color_Waves;
            uniform float _Speed;
            uniform samplerCUBE _CubMap;
            uniform float _Reflection;
            struct VertexInput {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float3 normal : NORMAL;
                float4 tangent : TANGENT;
                float4 texcoord0 : TEXCOORD0;
            };
            struct VertexOutput {
                float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                float4 uv0 : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 posWorld : TEXCOORD1;
                float3 normalDir : TEXCOORD2;
                float3 tangentDir : TEXCOORD3;
                float3 bitangentDir : TEXCOORD4;
                LIGHTING_COORDS(5,6)
                UNITY_FOG_COORDS(7)
            };
            VertexOutput vert (VertexInput v) {
                VertexOutput o = (VertexOutput)0;
                o.uv0 = v.texcoord0;
                o.normalDir = UnityObjectToWorldNormal(v.normal);
                o.tangentDir = normalize( mul( unity_ObjectToWorld, float4( v.tangent.xyz, 0.0 ) ).xyz );
                o.bitangentDir = normalize(cross(o.normalDir, o.tangentDir) * v.tangent.w);
                float4 node_9273 = _Time + _TimeEditor;
                float2 node_9735 = (o.uv0+(node_9273.r*_Speed)*float2(0,1));
                float4 _Waves_var = tex2Dlod(_Waves,float4(TRANSFORM_TEX(node_9735, _Waves),0.0,0));
                v.vertex.xyz += (_Waves_var.r*v.normal*_Intensity_Waves);
                o.posWorld = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex);
                float3 lightColor = _LightColor0.rgb;
                o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex );
                UNITY_TRANSFER_FOG(o,o.pos);
                TRANSFER_VERTEX_TO_FRAGMENT(o)
                return o;
            }
            sampler2D _ReflectionTex;
            float4 frag(VertexOutput i) : COLOR {
                i.normalDir = normalize(i.normalDir);
                float3x3 tangentTransform = float3x3( i.tangentDir, i.bitangentDir, i.normalDir);
                float3 viewDirection = normalize(_WorldSpaceCameraPos.xyz - i.posWorld.xyz);
                float4 node_1446 = _Time + _TimeEditor;
                float2 node_4184 = (i.uv0+node_1446.g*float2(0.0002,0.0001));
                float3 _Normal_1_var = UnpackNormal(tex2D(_Normal_1,TRANSFORM_TEX(node_4184, _Normal_1)));
                float2 node_5576 = (i.uv0+node_1446.g*float2(0.0002,-0.0001));
                float3 _Normal_2_var = UnpackNormal(tex2D(_Normal_2,TRANSFORM_TEX(node_5576, _Normal_2)));



                float3 normalLocal = (_Normal_1_var.rgb+_Normal_2_var.rgb);
                //Expiremental
                float4 uv1 = i.uv0;
                half4 refl = tex2Dproj( _ReflectionTex, UNITY_PROJ_COORD(uv1) );



                float3 normalDirection = normalize(mul( normalLocal, tangentTransform )); // Perturbed normals
                float3 viewReflectDirection = reflect( -viewDirection, normalDirection );
                float3 lightDirection = normalize(_WorldSpaceLightPos0.xyz);
                float3 lightColor = _LightColor0.rgb;
                float3 halfDirection = normalize(viewDirection+lightDirection);

/// Final Color:
                float3 finalColor = diffuse + specular + emissive;
               fixed4 finalRGBA = fixed4(finalColor,1);
           finalRGBA.rgb = lerp( finalColor.rgb, refl.rgb, 1);              finalRGBA.a = refl.a;
                UNITY_APPLY_FOG(i.fogCoord, finalRGBA);
                return finalRGBA;
            }
            ENDCG
```

Второй шейдер, FX/Water

```
Shader "FX/Water" { // Умеет класть текстуру прямо на экран!
Properties {
    _WaveScale ("Wave scale", Range (0.002,0.15)) = 0.063
    _ReflDistort ("Reflection distort", Range (0,15)) = 0.44
    [NoScaleOffset] _Fresnel ("Fresnel (A) ", 2D) = "gray" {}
    [NoScaleOffset] _BumpMap ("Normalmap ", 2D) = "bump" {}
    WaveSpeed ("Wave speed (map1 x,y; map2 x,y)", Vector) = (19,9,-16,-7)
    [NoScaleOffset] _ReflectiveColor ("Reflective color (RGB) fresnel (A) ", 2D) = "" {}
    _HorizonColor ("Simple water horizon color", COLOR)  = ( .172, .463, .435, 1)
     _ReflectionTex ("Internal Reflection", 2D) = "" {}
}


// -----------------------------------------------------------
// Fragment program cards


Subshader {
    Tags { "WaterMode"="Refractive" "RenderType"="Opaque" }
    Pass {
CGPROGRAM
#pragma vertex vert
#pragma fragment frag
#pragma multi_compile_fog




#include "UnityCG.cginc"

struct appdata {
    float4 vertex : POSITION;
    float3 normal : NORMAL;
};

struct v2f {
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
    #if defined(HAS_REFLECTION) || defined(HAS_REFRACTION)
        float4 ref : TEXCOORD0;
        float2 bumpuv0 : TEXCOORD1;
        float2 bumpuv1 : TEXCOORD2;
        float3 viewDir : TEXCOORD3;
    #else
        float2 bumpuv0 : TEXCOORD0;
        float2 bumpuv1 : TEXCOORD1;
        float3 viewDir : TEXCOORD2;
    #endif
    UNITY_FOG_COORDS(4)
};

v2f vert(appdata v)
{
    v2f o;
    o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);


    // scroll bump waves
    float4 temp;
    float4 wpos = mul (unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex);
    temp.xyzw = wpos.xzxz * _WaveScale4 + _WaveOffset;
    o.bumpuv0 = temp.xy;
    o.bumpuv1 = temp.wz;

    // object space view direction (will normalize per pixel)
    o.viewDir.xzy = WorldSpaceViewDir(v.vertex);

    #if defined(HAS_REFLECTION) || defined(HAS_REFRACTION)
    o.ref = ComputeNonStereoScreenPos(o.pos);
    #endif

    UNITY_TRANSFER_FOG(o,o.pos);
    return o;
}

sampler2D _ReflectionTex;



half4 frag( v2f i ) : SV_Target
{
    i.viewDir = normalize(i.viewDir);

    // combine two scrolling bumpmaps into one
    half3 bump1 = UnpackNormal(tex2D( _BumpMap, i.bumpuv0 )).rgb;
    half3 bump2 = UnpackNormal(tex2D( _BumpMap, i.bumpuv1 )).rgb;
    half3 bump = (bump1 + bump2) * 0.5;

    // fresnel factor
    half fresnelFac = dot( i.viewDir, bump );

    // perturb reflection/refraction UVs by bumpmap, and lookup colors

    float4 uv1 = i.ref; uv1.xy += bump * _ReflDistort;
    half4 refl = tex2Dproj( _ReflectionTex, UNITY_PROJ_COORD(uv1) );


    // final color is between refracted and reflected based on fresnel
    half4 color;

    half4 water = tex2D( _ReflectiveColor, float2(fresnelFac,fresnelFac) );
    color.rgb = lerp( water.rgb, refl.rgb, water.a );
    color.a = refl.a * water.a;


    UNITY_APPLY_FOG(i.fogCoord, color);
    return color;
}
ENDCG

    }
}

}
```

Comment: "ваш" шейдер явно сделан в визуальном редакторе, о чем говорят странные имена переменных - `node_1446` и прочие наборы цифр. Мало того, что это абсолютно не читаемый код из таких переменных, так вы еще его и урезали, что мешает его даже у себя локально на машине запустить. Каких-то визуальных примеров взамен вы тоже не предоставили. Крайне сомневаюсь, что кто-то будет разбирать и решать этот вопрос в таком виде - добавьте подробностей или этот вопрос потенциально могут закрыть, как требующим правки.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Дело оказалось в одной команде, которая и переводила все в экранные координаты

```
o.ref = ComputeNonStereoScreenPos(o.pos);
```

Применив её в вертексной части первого шейдера, получим необходимый нам результат. Только необходимо вместо `ref` взять аналогичную переменную из `TEXTCOORD0`

```
o.uv0 = ComputeNonStereoScreenPos(o.uv0);
```

Итак, итоговый код нужного шейдера

```
Shader "Oney" {  //Всем хорош, но не может в наложение текстур на экран. 
    Properties {
        _Color ("Color", Color) = (0.7016652,0.8427501,0.9264706,1)
        _Color_Waves ("Color_Waves", Color) = (0.1096453,0.3823529,0.2920773,1)
        _Normal_1 ("Normal_1", 2D) = "bump" {}
        _Normal_2 ("Normal_2", 2D) = "bump" {}
        _Waves ("Waves", 2D) = "white" {}
        _CubMap ("CubMap", Cube) = "_Skybox" {}
        _Intensity_Waves ("Intensity_Waves", Range(0, 50)) = 10
        _Speed ("Speed", Range(0, 1)) = 0.1
        _Intensity_Color ("Intensity_Color", Range(0, 10)) = 5
        _Spec ("Spec", Range(0, 2)) = 1
        _Gloss ("Gloss", Range(0, 2)) = 1
        _Reflection ("Reflection", Range(0, 2)) = 0
         _ReflectionTex ("Internal Reflection", 2D) = "" {}
    }
    SubShader {
        Tags {
            "RenderType"="Opaque"
        }
        Pass {
            Name "FORWARD"
            Tags {
                "LightMode"="ForwardBase"
            }


            CGPROGRAM

            uniform sampler2D _Normal_2; uniform float4 _Normal_2_ST;
            uniform float _Intensity_Color;
            uniform float4 _Color_Waves;
            uniform float _Speed;
            uniform samplerCUBE _CubMap;
            uniform float _Reflection;
            struct VertexInput {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float3 normal : NORMAL;
                float4 tangent : TANGENT;
                float4 texcoord0 : TEXCOORD0;
            };
            struct VertexOutput {
                float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                float4 uv0 : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 posWorld : TEXCOORD1;
                float3 normalDir : TEXCOORD2;
                float3 tangentDir : TEXCOORD3;
                float3 bitangentDir : TEXCOORD4;
                LIGHTING_COORDS(5,6)
                UNITY_FOG_COORDS(7)
            };
            VertexOutput vert (VertexInput v) {
                VertexOutput o = (VertexOutput)0;
                o.uv0 = v.texcoord0;
                o.normalDir = UnityObjectToWorldNormal(v.normal);
                o.tangentDir = normalize( mul( unity_ObjectToWorld, float4( v.tangent.xyz, 0.0 ) ).xyz );
                o.bitangentDir = normalize(cross(o.normalDir, o.tangentDir) * v.tangent.w);
                float4 node_9273 = _Time + _TimeEditor;
                float2 node_9735 = (o.uv0+(node_9273.r*_Speed)*float2(0,1));
                float4 _Waves_var = tex2Dlod(_Waves,float4(TRANSFORM_TEX(node_9735, _Waves),0.0,0));
                v.vertex.xyz += (_Waves_var.r*v.normal*_Intensity_Waves);
                o.posWorld = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex);
                float3 lightColor = _LightColor0.rgb;
                o.uv0 = ComputeNonStereoScreenPos(o.uv0);<---Добавляем этот кусок кода сюда
                o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex );
                UNITY_TRANSFER_FOG(o,o.pos);
                TRANSFER_VERTEX_TO_FRAGMENT(o)
                return o;
            }
            sampler2D _ReflectionTex;
            float4 frag(VertexOutput i) : COLOR {
                i.normalDir = normalize(i.normalDir);
                float3x3 tangentTransform = float3x3( i.tangentDir, i.bitangentDir, i.normalDir);
                float3 viewDirection = normalize(_WorldSpaceCameraPos.xyz - i.posWorld.xyz);
                float4 node_1446 = _Time + _TimeEditor;
                float2 node_4184 = (i.uv0+node_1446.g*float2(0.0002,0.0001));
                float3 _Normal_1_var = UnpackNormal(tex2D(_Normal_1,TRANSFORM_TEX(node_4184, _Normal_1)));
                float2 node_5576 = (i.uv0+node_1446.g*float2(0.0002,-0.0001));
                float3 _Normal_2_var = UnpackNormal(tex2D(_Normal_2,TRANSFORM_TEX(node_5576, _Normal_2)));



                float3 normalLocal = (_Normal_1_var.rgb+_Normal_2_var.rgb);
                //Expiremental
                float4 uv1 = i.uv0;
                half4 refl = tex2Dproj( _ReflectionTex, UNITY_PROJ_COORD(uv1) );



                float3 normalDirection = normalize(mul( normalLocal, tangentTransform )); // Perturbed normals
                float3 viewReflectDirection = reflect( -viewDirection, normalDirection );
                float3 lightDirection = normalize(_WorldSpaceLightPos0.xyz);
                float3 lightColor = _LightColor0.rgb;
                float3 halfDirection = normalize(viewDirection+lightDirection);

/// Final Color:
                float3 finalColor = diffuse + specular + emissive;
               fixed4 finalRGBA = fixed4(finalColor,1);
           finalRGBA.rgb = lerp( finalColor.rgb, refl.rgb, 1);              finalRGBA.a = refl.a;
                UNITY_APPLY_FOG(i.fogCoord, finalRGBA);
                return finalRGBA;
```